# How do I set the selected position of a list

Tags: android

I have a listview in and android app that has almost 1400 elements in that will be available when the app starts. I am trying to implement a process where when user selects item, say item number 1257 in that list of 1400 items. The activity changes as it should but then when the user returns I want that item to be redisplayed without having to scroll through 1256 items to get to it currently I use smoothScrollToPosition to get to the item but what it does is scroll itself and it takes several seconds to get there.

I did try the setposition but it never worked for me.

Is that the normal process or is there a way to jump directly there without having to watch the app scroll by itself.

Overall it does get there faster than when I scroll it but when going through that many items I was hoping for a better solution.

Any ideas
Here is the code where I so the listview

```
list1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter=new LazyAdapterB(this, mStrings, list, desc, audiotrack, audiotracksize, appSKU, purchased);
list1.setAdapter(adapter);

list1.smoothScrollToPosition(1258);


list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
    View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Intent myIntent;
    myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
    myBundle.putString("image", mStrings[arg2]);
    myBundle.putString("title", list[arg2]);
    myBundle.putString("desc", desc[arg2]);
    myBundle.putString("purchased", purchased[arg2]);
    myBundle.putString("audiotrack", audiotrack[arg2]);
    myBundle.putString("audiotracksize", audiotracksize[arg2]);
    myBundle.putString("appSKU", appSKU[arg2]);
    myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Am I doing this in the right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [`setSelection(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29)

e.g.

```
 list1.setSelection(1258);
```

Comment: Ok first of all Thank you very much this .....but this bugs me because this is my code showing my previous attempts                //list1.setSelection(123);
         //list1.scrollBy(0, (123*40));
         //list1.setSelected(true);
         //list1.scrollTo(0, (123*40));
         list1.setSelection(123+5);     I commentted them out since then because it didnot work but now I try it and it works.